# In ASP.NET WebApi, why is RouteData's value type "object" and not "string"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

In WebApi, `RouteData` has a `Values` property which is where route data is stored. For some reason, however, it implements `IDictionary<string, object>` rather than `IDictionary<string, string>`. Is the value type ever not going to be a string?

The context is that I'm writing a custom `IHttpRouteConstraint` to check if an integer is inside a specified range. In order to do this, I must cast my value to `string` and then use `int.TryParse`. But this will fail if the value is actually an `int`. Can this ever happen?

Comment: Is your route parameter an integer in the target controller action?

Comment: In this case, no. The parameter needs to match the constraint and is discarded.

If it was an integer in the controller target, that shouldn't still affect it I think, because model binding happens later, no?

Comment: model binding happens later => yes. `But this will fail if the value is actually an int` => this should never happen.

Comment: But why should it never happen? That's what's confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) ,you'll notice Unit Tests where the value is not a string(for example [BindValuesAsync_RouteData_Values_To_Simple_Types](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Http.Integration.Test/ModelBinding/DefaultActionValueBinderTest.cs)).

You said you are writing a custom constraint,let's take this one:

```
 public class MyConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
 {
       public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
       {
            string parameters = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values.Select(p => p.Value.GetType().FullName).ToArray());
            return true;
       }
  }
```

You register it:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
                                   "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                                   new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, 
                                   new { isLocal = new MyConstraint() });
```

Assuming you have this controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(int id) { return "Value"; }
}
```

If you make a GET request to "/api/values/Get/1"  you'll notice the the values are of type

- System.String   //values
- System.String   //Get
- System.String   //1

But

If you make a GET request to "/api/values/1"  you'll notice the the values are of type

- System.String //values
- System.String //1
- System.Web.Http.RouteParameter

If you see the [source code of the class](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/RouteParameter.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="RouteParameter"/> class can be used to indicate properties about a route parameter (the literals and placeholders 
/// located within segments of a <see cref="M:IHttpRoute.RouteTemplate"/>). 
/// It can for example be used to indicate that a route parameter is optional.
/// </summary>
public sealed class RouteParameter
{
    public static readonly RouteParameter Optional = new RouteParameter();

    // singleton constructor
    private RouteParameter()        {   }

    public override string ToString()   {  return string.Empty;      }
}
```

So, one occasion this is not a string is when you don't provide optional arguments.
You should first check the type of the object and only if it is a non empty string,try to parse it